# Will aggregations run on a replica slow down write rate of the primary?

Tags: mongodb

I need to accept data at a high rate and I need to aggregate this data periodically. My current strategy is to have a replica on a different server which will act as a "processor" of the data by using aggregations.

My question is whether running aggregations on a replica may slow down primary?

Comment: Replica sets **are not for load distribution**. Thats sharding. Please be more specific. Define high rate, both in numbers and sizes, and state the dimensions and setup of your servers, so that we can see wether your hardware matches the requirements. In general: Each operation utilizing the disk will slow down all other disk operations. Will it be considerable in decently sized HW? Not likely.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I don't have any specific numbers, this is an abstract Q raised in my head while thinking over  a "what if" situation. It can be further generalized into "how to process (readonly) data with minimal effect on query and write operations"

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from replicas for read-only workloads. Although your replicas tend to wear down from write operations, as much as the primary, you may dedicate the primary to write operations and read only from replicas. Off course this is subject to lagging, once the replicas could not be able to catch it up with the primary just-in-time. Anyway, theoretically, no read operation on a replica should impact the primary, including aggregations.

PS: Sharding is always better for load distribution, off course, but it doesn't mean replicas are completely useless for that.

Comment: Originally I thought that could be addressed by lazily duping db into readonly copy. I guess I need to read further into sharding.